# Log4j2 within web application with jsf 2

Tags: jsf-2, log4j2

According with log4j and log4j2 documentation it's work well using tld with jsp pages.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-taglib/tagreference.html#log.tld

It is possible to be used with xmlns:log="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/tld/log" within jsp 2 xhtml page ?

My java faces web-app 3.0 catch the following error.

```
This page calls for XML namespace http://logging.apache.org/log4j/tld/log declared with prefix log but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

My web environment is:

- Java 1.6.0_38
- Tomcat 7.0.50
- Mojarra JSF 2.2.4
- Primefaces RC 4.0
- log4j2-beta9 (/web-INF/lib/ with log4j-1.2-api-2.0-beta9.jar,log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar,log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar,log4j-taglib-2.0-beta9.jar)

Any feedback it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind raising this on the Log4j2 issue tracker?
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2

Comment: Now it works on log4j2 stable release. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html